# Attendee invitation is not sent?

Tags: android, calendar

I am generating an calendar events based on filled form and I don't use an intend method but direct insert via URI. Suddenly sending invitation to the attendee stopped working.
This is part of the code where the invitation should be initiated:

```
    ContentResolver atend = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "Vet");
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, vetemail);
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE);
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_OPTIONAL);
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
    val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
    Uri muri = atend.insert(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, val);
    Log.d("Atendees URI:",muri.toString());
    long Aeventid=Long.parseLong(muri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: Can you please provide information on last actions before it stopped sending invitations. Codes don't just stop doing things. What was the last change you did?

Comment: Yes I found out that I put wrong CalendarID... but I still don't have to correct method to fetch the default or gmail calendar ID .